# How to sort composite in Elasticsearch , given by the list or interger?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I am working with ELS , I have a composite aggs with : `id` and `name` .
Let say there are 6 documents

`[1, Name A] , [2, Name B] , [3, Name C] , [4, Name D], [5, Name E], [6, Name C]`

How do I do a sort , given I have a list integer want to display first [2,3,6]. Then I would like to sort order asc the id and then by name. The result will be :

`[2, Name B] , [3, Name C] , [6, Name C] ,[1, Name A] , [4, Name D], [5, Name E]`.

I tried to search alot and read the document , but cannot find the solution for it. Can you help me , Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [script sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-sort-context.html).

**Sample doc**

```
{
        "_index" : "index67",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "CbVPMX0BmfuoBV6EES56",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "EmpNo" : 1,
          "Name" : "A"
        }
      }
```

**Query**

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "if(params.ids.contains((int)doc['EmpNo'].value)) return 1; return 2;",
          "params": {
            "ids": [
              2,
              3,
              6
            ]
          }
        },
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name.keyword": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```